# "Use" the Perl file that h2ph generated from a C header?

Tags: c, perl

The `h2ph` utility generates a .ph "Perl header" file from a C header file, but what is the best way to use this file?  Like, should it be `require` or `use`?:

```
require 'myconstants.ph';
# OR
use myconstants;  # after mv myconstants.ph myconstants.pm
# OR, something else?
```

Right now, I am doing the `use` version shown above, because with that one I never need to type parentheses after the constant.  I want to type MY_CONSTANT and not MY_CONSTANT(), and I have `use strict` and `use warnings` in effect in the Perl files where I need the constants.

It's a bit strange though to do a `use` with this file since it doesn't have a module name declared, and it doesn't seem to be particularly intended to be a module.

I have just one file I am running through h2ph, not a hundred or anything.

I've looked at `perldoc h2ph`, but it didn't mention the subject of the intended mechanism of import at all.

**Example input and output**: For further background, here's an example input file and what h2ph generates from it:

```c
// File myconstants.h
#define MY_CONSTANT 42
```

...

```
# File myconstants.ph - generated via h2ph -d . myconstants.h
require '_h2ph_pre.ph';
no warnings qw(redefine misc);
eval 'sub MY_CONSTANT () {42;}' unless defined(&MY_CONSTANT);
1;
```

**Problem example**: Here's an example of "the problem," where I need to use parentheses to get the code to compile with use strict:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
require 'myconstants.ph';

sub main {
    print "Hello world " . MY_CONSTANT;  # error until parentheses are added
}
main;
```

which produces the following error:

```
Bareword "MY_CONSTANT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at main.pl line 7.
Execution of main.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**Conclusion**: So is there a better or more typical way that this is used, as far as following best practices for importing a file like `myconstants.ph`?  How would Larry Wall do it?

Comment: Please, don't write `sub main { } main;`. This isn't C. Perl programs run in `package main` automatically and there is no reason to factor any code into a `sub` if it will only be run once. And when you factor your code out, always call your subs with parens (e.g. `main();`).

Comment: I do the main function for one very practical reason: when I enter the debugger I can type "c ::main" and that immediately jumps me to the code I care about, whereas otherwise it can be a bit of a chore to get to that line in Perl, especially since what happens right at launch in the debugger varies by the use statements you have. As you can see I don't think Perl is C since this question relates strongly to *keeping* the Perl ability not to use parens, which is very unlike C. If you believe it's a best practice to always use parens, which is like C, well TMTOWTDI, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should `require` your file. As you have discovered, `use` accepts only a *bareword* module name, and it is wrong to rename `myconstants.ph` to have a `.pm` suffix just so that `use` works.

The choice of `use` or `require` makes *no difference* to whether parentheses are needed when you use a constant in your code. The resulting `.ph` file defines constants in the same way as the [`constant`](https://metacpan.org/module/constant) module, and all you need in the huge majority of cases is the bare identifier. One exception to this is when you are using the constant as a hash key, when

```
my %hash = { CONSTANT => 99 }
my $val = $hash{CONSTANT}
```

doesn't work, as you are using the string `CONSTANT` as a key. Instead, you must write

```
my %hash = { CONSTANT() => 99 }
my $val = $hash{CONSTANT()}
```

You may also want to wrap your `require` inside a `BEGIN` block, like this

```
BEGIN {
  require 'myconstants.ph';
}
```

to make sure that the values are available to all other parts of your code, including anything in subsequent `BEGIN` blocks.

Comment: Require alone results in parentheses being necessary as I said and that is what the crux of my question is about.  I will post a complete example of that. I just looked up BEGIN and If I had multiple of these files to import, you seem to be saying that they would all have to be wrapped in individual BEGIN statements.  That seems laborious and a little ludicrous - is it normal Perl programming practice?  I would rather rename the file and add a module name (package statement near the top). If I add that module name, would a purist be happy that the resulting module is a valid module?

Comment: @user62177541: It is too easy to damn a language for being *"a little ludicrous"* just because its behaviour is different from what you are used to. The problem here is that `require` is executed at run time, so the definition of `MY_CONSTANT` isn't available during the compilation pass and Perl reports an error. You don't need a `BEGIN` block for each `require`: you can put list of `require` statements inside a single begin block. In fact you can write anything you like in there, so you could just have `BEGIN { require $_ for glob '*.ph' }` if you preferred.

Comment: I didn't notice I was damning the language, so that's quite a leap you're making there, but could you please answer the question in the last sentence.  I'm honestly quite curious how a Perl pro sees that one.

Comment: Whenever I've seen constants pulled in from an h2ph file, it's been with require - just look at the code it generates! These aren't modules with package definitions and shouldn't be treated as if they were. Furthermore, when said constants are actually used, again in the code I've seen, they're called using `&CONSTANT`. It really depends on the intended audience for your code. Are you writing a module where you'll force others to `require` these header files? If so, you might consider porting the constants to `Readonly` which will give you real variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does somewhat lie in the `require`.

Since `require` is a statement that will be evaluated at *run-time*, it *cannot* have any effect on the *parsing* of the latter part of the script. So when perl reads through the `MY_CONSTANT` in the `print` statement, it does not even know the existence of the subroutine, and will parse it as a bareword.

It is the same for `eval`.

One solution, as mentioned by others, is to put it into a `BEGIN` block. Alternatively, you may forward-delcare it by yourself:

```
require 'some-file';
sub MY_CONSTANT;
print 'some text' . MY_CONSTANT;
```

Finally, from my perspective, I have not ever used any `ph` files in my Perl programming.